# How to check if the value matches the one from previous ?th row? (? is dynamic)

Tags: loops, match, conditional-statements, lag, seq

Here is my data set. 
[Data in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQNeY.png)

I'd like to check if the gender with "Potential Original" matched the gender with "Potential Duplicate'. There is no specified group but 1 duplicate + 1 or more original acted like a group.

Here is the output I want (for duplicate it's NA because it's comparing to itself). 
[Data out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vojn.png)

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code your tried

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rahul for looking into this. This is what I tried and I think it worked. The logic is to create the seq # first for each block of Duplicate and Original and then pull the lag value with corresponding distance.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, counter := seq_len(.N), by = list(cumsum(Status == "Potential 
 Duplicate"))]

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$Status[i]=="Potential Duplicate") {
   df$Gender_LAG[i] <-df2$Gender[i]
                                             } 
   else {
     df$Gender_LAG[i]<-df2$Gender[i-df2$counter[i]+1]
        }
                        }
```

Thanks.
Looking forwards to seeing other options.